# How to move cell colour when sorting data

Tags: excel, excel-2010

In my spreadsheet I have coloured rows but when I sort the data the colours stay in the same place and don't follow the sorted data.

So if row B is red and the data moves to row A after sorting, row B remains red but I want row A to be red because that's where the corresponding data has moved to.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using conditional formatting for the color?

Comment: Are you sorting the entire area, or just specific columns?

Comment: I'm not using conditional formatting and I'm sorting the entire area

Comment: You should look at conditional formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a table and have applied a table style. You need to convert the table to a range, then convert it back. Do the following:

1. Select a cell in the the table, then under the 'Table Tools' > 'Design' tab, select Convert to Range. Select yes at the pop-up asking whether you'd like to convert it to a normal range.
2. Highlight the whole table again, the under the 'Insert' tab, select table. Click on ok in the pop-up window.

The formatting should remain consistent now when you're sort the data.